# How can I use didSet to change the text of a UITextField (IBOutlet)?

Tags: swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I'd like to set text value of UITextField (IBOutlet) in the DidSet of my model object that I pass.

Here the code:

```
    let manageSettingViewController: ManageSettingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ManageSettingViewController") as ManageSettingViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewControllerCustom(manageSettingViewController)
    manageSettingViewController.setting = setting
```

And in the didSet of manageSettingViewController:

```
   var setting: Setting? {
    didSet
    {
        keyTextField.text = setting?.label
        valueTextField.text = setting?.value
    }
```

How can I set the text? Because in this case Xcode crash because "keyTextField is nil" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `manageSettingViewController.setting` right after instantiating `manageSettingViewController` -- at this point, it hasn't loaded its view from the nib/storyboard yet, so all of its `IBOutlet` variables (which presumably `keyTextField` and `valueTextField` are) are still nil. Those text fields are hooked up as of when `ManageSettingViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method is called.

You could change your `didSet` to check the optional outlets before setting them, or assign through optional chaining:

```
didSet {
    keyTextField?.text = setting?.label
    valueTextField?.text = setting?.value
}
```

This would avoid the crash, but it would also fail to change your text field's content. You'd have to also implement `viewDidLoad` for `ManageSettingViewController` to check its `setting` property and set its text fields accordingly.

Of course, that would duplicate the code from your `didSet`. That code might still be useful if you want to set `setting` from elsewhere and have the UI update automatically, but `didSet` won't help you for updating UI before the UI loads.

Comment: With objective c I often used this pattern. And to avoid duplicating code I added self.setting = self.setting in viewDidLoad to trigger the setter again. However, this isn't possible with swift anymore. Any idea for a workaround for this?